# Center a wider div in a narrower one

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="narrow">
   <div id="wide">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have one div, and another one inside it that is wider than the parent.

The `#narrow` div has a changeable width, and the `#wide` div has a fixed width.

How do I center the `#wide` div inside the `#narrow` div so that **both** the left and right side of #wide div are trimmed when `#narrow` is given `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: `How do I center the #wide div inside the #narrow div so that the left and right side of #wide div are trimmed? ` - `Second, how to prevent a descendent from flowing out of the ancestor's box` I think he actually wants the child to overflow outside the parent.

Comment: @PointedEars there is one question here: how to make the `#narrow` divider trim **both** sides of the `#wide` divider. This isn't really a basic question. `overflow:hidden` alone will only trim one side.

Comment: @Ejay No, read again. "… so that the left and right side of #wide div are trimmed."

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes, it is. Once horizontally centered in the ancestor, a wider descendant will *always* be clipped, *if* clipped, on *both* sides.

Comment: @PointedEars yes, I've read that :) It still seems to me that he wants two `<div>` elements' centers aligned to each other. **edit: no matter if the child is wider than the parent**

Comment: @PointedEars there currently isn't a working answer to this question. If it's as basic as you've mentioned, why aren't you answering it yourself?

Comment: @Ejay It is *inherent* to centering something in something else that the two centers are aligned.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Stack Overflow should not support laziness.

Comment: @PointedEars looking forward to your _basic_ answer and something in the _manual_ that **directly** addresses this scenario. For me _right answer speaks louder than comments_ :)

Comment: @Ejay @JamesDonnelly Apparently I was wrong about this CSS feature. I assumed, without checking, that `margin: 0 auto` also applied if the descendant was wider than its context as long as `overflow` was used. Absolute positioning appears to be the correct solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can center the wide div by using `position: absolute` and then using negative `margin-left` to position it centered. Note that this works only when the element has a fixed width.

[**JS-Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwy5T/5/)

```
#narrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; //may be variable
}

#wide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px; // half the width
    width: 300px; // must be fixed
}
```

To hide the part that's flowing over the narrow div, you can use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: The `#narrow` divider has a fluid width.

Comment: You are a genius! This works perfectly! Thank you, thank you, thank you, I've been trying to figure this out whole day long!

Comment: It's a common problem I've faced already a few times :)
@JamesDonnelly: My example works for variable widths.

Comment: I think it solves the OP's problem if the child has constant width. Now, for figuring out for myself, this doesn't work when child and parent width is variable. http://jsfiddle.net/Rwy5T/4/
Edit: Ok noticed your disclaimer :) can you figure out a way to make it work when both width are variable. That'll be valuable solution :)

Comment: @Nirazul Variable: Only if you also use negative percentage margins. A remaining problem is that there are issues with shallow viewports and horizontal scrolling. Perhaps CSS Computed Values will offer a solution sometime.

Comment: @PointedEars: That's true, the wide div can't be variable, but that was no prerequisite on this one. As of Computed Values: CSS-Preprocessors already help lessen the burden :)

Comment: @Nirazul You misunderstand. My point was that you need percentage margin widths for `#wide` if `#narrow` has variable width. As for CSS preprocessors, they can only help with precomputed absolute values. If you want an *adaptive* client-side solution *without* percentages, you currently need client-side scripting to compute those values dynamically. But that is comparably ugly.

Comment: @PointedEars: That's not true. I've updated my example with a variable width inline-Element. As you can see: The wide div is still centered. Or do I misunderstand you again?
The only dependancy left is the following line: `margin-left: -150px;` which corresponds to half of the wide div's width.

Answer (score -1):

Easy with css:

`#narrow {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: No this does not center, it crops the `#wide` div.